# Heroku multiple commands in Docker deployment

Tags: docker, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to execute multiple steps after Heroku builds the container with my Python Django application inside.

What I started with in `heroku.yml` (and it worked just fine), was:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

Now, I'd like to run migrations as well, and run some other commands (I'm using sqlite database), but the following does not work, and does not produce any output.

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python manage.py makemigrations --no-input && python manage.py migrate --no-input && python manage.py migrate auth --no-input && python manage.py makemigrations auth --no-input && python manage.py migrate --no-input --run-syncdb && echo "from django.contrib.auth.models import User; User.objects.create_superuser('user', 'user@example.com', 'example', first_name='The', last_name='User')" | python manage.py shell"
```

Do you know what I could be missing here? I'm using Free Heroku plan.

I tried wrapping the commands in `bash -c "COMMANDS GO HERE"`, but then it get errors of `python` not found (tried both `python` and `python3`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get it working. In the `heroku.yml`, just call the shell script containing all the steps:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - ./on_release.sh
```

For me, it worked when I placed the script in the workdir of my container (the same place where `manage.py` resides). I couldn't find more information about how exactly it works alltogether.

From `heroku logs -t`, it turns out that Heroku already uses "bash -c" under the hood (probably that's also how Docker wraps the commands from Yaml file).